# How to disable screen stretching in Linux AMDGPU

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, display, amdgpu

Kinda new to Linux Gaming stuff and recently I'm running a Kubuntu with AMDGPU and by default the screen stretches on different aspect ratios than my default (21:9). On Windows is easy to change this using AMDs Radeon Software but I don't know what configuration I must change on Xorg.

I don't know what information might help but my Xorg configuration includes VRR; also running `for output in $(xrandr --prop | grep -E -o -i "^[A-Z\-]+-[0-9]+"); do xrandr --output "$output" --set "scaling mode" "Full aspect"; done` didn't work for me.